# WebRTC server (mediasoup) throws SSL error, but only for Firefox (?!)

Tags: openssl, webrtc, mediasoup

I'm running the popular open-source [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/) WebRTC server on a standalone box with no firewalls, fresh SSL certs installed and literally nothing else running on the machine (no web server, no database server, nothing). When my video chat app tries to stream video through this server, to a client using Firefox, mediasoup emits an SSL error (2nd line below):

```
mediasoup:WARN:mediasoup-worker [id:gxzingwt#3] RTC::DtlsTransport::OnSslInfo() | received DTLS fatal alert: bad certificate +0ms
mediasoup:ERROR:mediasoup-worker [id:gxzingwt#3] RTC::DtlsTransport::CheckStatus() | OpenSSL error [desc:'SSL status: SSL_ERROR_SSL', error:'error:14102412:SSL routines:dtls1_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate'] +0ms
mediasoup:WARN:mediasoup-worker [id:gxzingwt#3] RTC::DtlsTransport::CheckStatus() | connection failed +1ms
mediasoup:WARN:mediasoup-worker [id:gxzingwt#3] RTC::DtlsTransport::Reset() | resetting DTLS transport +1ms
mediasoup:WARN:mediasoup-worker [id:gxzingwt#3] RTC::WebRtcTransport::OnDtlsFailed() | DTLS failed +0ms
```

Now here's what weird, this ONLY happens with Firefox browser. For Safari, Chrome, and Safari iOS (phone/iPad), no problems at all. If I have 5 people broadcasting in my video chat room, I can open those and see/stream the video with no problems from the other browsers. But Firefox (the latest version, both developer edition and regular Firefox) cause mediasoup to throw that SSL error and the stream can't resolve and show the video to the user.

mediasoup is running on port 8443 and I've also tried it on port 443. I've checked the debug logs and can't find any other problems-- this SSL issue is it.

I thought perhaps my Let's Encrypt certs were bad, so I have revoked, deleted, and re-issued the SSL certs for the domain. No problems there or anything strange.

I've run `openssl s_client -connect [my domain running mediasoup].com:8443 -showcerts` and everything looks great, certs are fine-- the format matches the same output as my valid certs on my web server machine as well the same output from as a friend's WebRTC server. I also tried `openssl s_client -host [my domain].com -port 8443 -cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/[my domain].com/cert.pem -key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[my domain].com/privkey.pem` on the machine itself, all good. So I don't think it's the certs.

Since it's only Firefox giving these problems, I thought maybe Firefox was caching an old/invalid certificate somehow, so I deleted and cleaned Firefox's cache, and also looked in my Mac's Keychain Access app to see if there were any certs in there for the domain where mediasoup is running (there weren't).

What is going on?! ;-) Why does Firefox-- and only Firefox!-- cause mediasoup to throw this error, and prevent my users with Firefox from using the video chat? Again: with Chrome, Safari, iPad/iPhone, **everything works perfectly.**

(Or, how can I get that mediasoup-worker process to tell me more about EXACTLY why it doesn't like the SSL cert?)

(Also, why would it only be Firefox that is having problems? Could it be a certificate that is stored in Firefox that it sends to the mediasoup server to talk to it? I know the WebRTC protocol is complex and has a lot of negotiations, perhaps that's part of it... like maybe it's referring to a different certificate than the one on the server domain?)

Comment: the error is in the DTLS (udp) connection not the signaling connection which you tested. WebRTC uses self-signed certificates there whose fingerprints are exchanged in the SDP in terms of API. Using wireshark to capture the dtls handshake might be easiest (filter for `dtls`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the mediasoup forum is here: https://mediasoup.discourse.group

BTW, as Philipp says, mediasoup "is not listening in port 8443 or 443". That's the WebSocket server of the **mediasoup-demo** project. mediasoup does not listen by itself for HTTP or WebSocket at all.

If you don't provide your TLS certificate to `mediasoup.createWorker()` then mediasoup will create its own random certificates for **DTLS**. And it's in DTLS where you see that error.

BTW I've tested in latest Firefox stable (68.0.2) and Nightly (70.0a1 (2019-08-14)) in OSX and I don't get any SSL error in DTLS, so honestly no idea.

PS: If you can provide more info (for example which mediasoup version you are using), please open an issue in mediasoup Discourse Group in the "mediasoup-demo" category.

Comment: THANK YOU - you helped me solve the problem. An SSL cert wasn't being passed to the mediasoup workers, so they were generating their own, and Firefox did NOT like that at all. (I did not originally write this code but I'm happy to debug it, lol) Not sure exactly why, but I solved the problem easily by just giving them a cert. Thank you for your quick help and idea about the workers, that was it!

Comment: I hope I have some idea about the mediasoup workers, I wrote them :)

Comment: Haha cool, thank you @Iñaki for responding here... it's clear you're an expert. ;-) And thanks for such a great job on mediasoup, it's a really nice piece of software and a very valuable contribution to the open-source and WebRTC communities. My app uses mediasoup v2 but I'm hoping to get the developer to upgrade it to take advantages of v3. Much appreciated ❤️

Comment: BTW kind of interesting that Firefox was unhappy with the lack of SSL certs, but Chrome and Safari had no problem. Does that mean Firefox doesn't implement WebRTC properly? Or maybe it means Chrome/Safari are just more forgiving and willing to overlook an SSL problem? Hmm.

Comment: I'm not aware of the Firefox issue with DTLS certs (never seen it), but feel free to report an issue in the Firefox tracker.